# White paper hashing clarification

Tags: consensus

On page 20 of the Stellar Consensus Protocol white paper the specifics of calculating a weighting for other nodes, the neighbours of a node and the priority of another node are all described. Specifically:

neighbors(v, n) = {v' | G_{i} (N, n, v') < h_{max} * weight(v, v')}

and

priority(n, v') = G_{i}(P, n, v')

where v and v' are nodes, n is a slot number h_{max} is the maximum value of the hashing function used and G_{i}(P, n, v') and G_{i} (N, n, v') are two different hash functions. This is according to the paper, because they take in the two constants, N and P.

My question is what exactly are N and P and how are they created/calculated and how are they given to the hash function to produce different hash functions. If this is too general, assume we are using SHA-256 (as I believe the stellar-core does) and give an answer specifically for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to p.10 of the [IETF draft](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-mazieres-dinrg-scp-04.pdf) about the Stellar Consensus Protocol, N=1 and P=2. Both are 32-bit XDR values.

The two hash functions are then SHA-256(1 || n || v) and SHA-256(2 || n || v), where "||" denotes the concatenation of serialized values.